# ModelMapper map abstract model to abstract dto

Tags: spring-boot, modelmapper

How can I do this mapping?

Models:

```
class Transaction {
  String code;
  Details details;
}

abstract class Details {}

class CardDetails extends Details {
  String cardNumber;
}
```

DTO:

```
class TransactionDTO {
  String code;
  DetailsDTO details;
}

abstract class DetailsDTO {}

class CardDetailsDTO extends DetailsDTO {
  String cardNumber;
}
```

The ModelMapper is mapping Transaction.code -> TransactionDTO.code but not Transaction.details -> TransactionDTO.details where both details are CardDetails and CardDetailsDTO respectively

Comment: Any specific reasons why you're using ModelMapper?